# Ruby on rails app hosted, but got an issue.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, web-hosting

Hello i deployed a rails app on heroku. 
http://infinite-falls-7346.herokuapp.com

The localhost app works fine.
The first page is nice After dat i get
 But the hosted one gives me error like

**We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

Do anyone have idea why it is like dat?

Comment: what do the logs say try "heroku logs" in console

Answer (score 0):

While deploying app on heroku most of the time at the beginning problem get with compiling the assets, mostly due to the asset pipe lines. Your local server may be fine as there is no precompilation but heroku can triggers un-expected errors due to small bug in the code that wasn't been hit on local environment.

Following link explain you the most of the debugging technique with heroku.

http://neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/ Could be useful in figuring out the problem.